# nonblocking SSL socket with multithreaded client blocking on read

Tags: sockets, session, ssl, openssl

I cannot write to the SSL server socket from threads which are run on the client (each thread creates a socket, CTX, SSL, ... separately).

## Client

The client runs 2 threads, each thread creates a SSL connection.
Each thread is performing three writes SSL_write:

### Thread1 - SSL session1

```
sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
SSL_CTX *ctx = setup_client_ctx();
ssl = SSL_new(ctx);
SSL_set_fd(ssl, sockfd);
err = SSL_connect(ssl);
```

The client connects to SSL and writes to the server:

```
SSL_write(..."message1"...);
SSL_write(..."message2"...);
SSL_write(..."message3"...);
```

The connection is kept open.

### Thread2 - SSL session2

```
sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
SSL_CTX *ctx = setup_client_ctx();
ssl = SSL_new(ctx)
SSL_set_fd(ssl, sockfd);
err = SSL_connect(ssl);
```

The client connects to SSL and writes to the server

```
SSL_write(..."message4"...)
SSL_write(..."message5"...)
SSL_write(..."message6"...)
```

After writes, the connection is kept open

## Server

```
while(true)
    {
       while (data_size > 0)
       {
          bytes_recv = SSL_read(ssl, data, data_size);
          if (bytes_recv <= 0)
          {         
             return bytes_recv;
          }

          data += bytes_recv;
          data_size -= bytes_recv;
       }
       return 1;
    }
```

## Result

Server runs the loop above. It receives the messages4-6 from the second thread and than hangs on SSL_read. The messages4-6 arrived on SSL session2, so I thought the SSL_read will return with the value 0, as I have non-blocking socket and there are no other data comming on this session. But it never returns. At the same time the client hangs in the thread1 on SSL_connect with session1, what means, that the message1 can not been sent.

I think the problem is with sessions and that the server is using the session from the previous connection of the thread2. What to do about that? Or is the problem somewhere else?

### This is a sample of trace messages

```
Started thread1 (session1)
Started thread2 (session2)
Going to connect to TCP sock from thread2
Going to connect to SSL sock from thread2
Going to connect to SSL from thread1
Writing to the server from thread2
Finished thread2
```

**Update**
It seems that network buffers are empty (because select doesn't pick up any incoming connection) and data from both sessions are in SSL buffer. SSL_read reads data from one session, and when next data are from different session, it just hangs.

Comment: Shouldn't you have 2 *ssl*s in the server one for each connection?

Comment: Can you please post your complete Server Code?